# I have a local Amazon Linux 2 (EC2) AMI Instance; How do I repartition the disk and expand the file system?

Tags: centos7, diskmanagement, fdisk, amazon-linux-2

I have expanded the disk of my VM.
How do I now repartition the disk and expand the file system on the guest?
Which is Amazon Linux 2
Kernel 4.14.252-195.483.amzn2.x86_64 on an x86_64

$> sudo lsblk
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda        8:0    0   52G  0 disk
├─sda1     8:1    0   25G  0 part /
└─sda128 259:0    0    1M  0 part
sr0       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

$> sudo fdisk -l
GPT PMBR size mismatch (52428799 != 109051903) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sda: 52 GiB, 55834574848 bytes, 109051904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B5D4B016-37AF-4CFE-A37B-2B3B6F23154F

Device      Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1    4096 52428766 52424671  25G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda128  2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

### sudo cfdisk (sorted) gives;

```
                            Disk: /dev/sda
                            Size: 52 GiB, 55834574848 bytes, 109051904 sectors
                            Label: gpt, identifier: B5D4B016-37AF-4CFE-A37B-2B3B6F23154F
```

Device              Start             End               Sectors        Size Type
/dev/sda1            2048              4095                2048          1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2            4096          52428766            52424671         25G Linux filesystem
Free space       52428800         109051870            56623071         27G

---

Based on the cfdisk output I'm guessing that I need to

1. create a new partition sda3 from the "Free Space"
2. add sda1, sda2 and the new sda3 to the same LVM

Can someone confirm the steps and let me know how this can be done from the CLI it would be much appreciated?
Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem ...
follow this procedure and you'll have it done!

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/extend-linux-file-system

PLEASE!?! Do NOT skip the first step, where you take a snapshot of the volume BEFORE you start screwing around with data storage.

Comment: So based on this answer; `$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 1` to expand sda1 and I used `$ sudo xfs_growfs /dev/sda1` as a direct replacement for resize2fs.